# Material UI menu button inside a table with pagination and sort does not work after second page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with React and using Material UI.
I'm building a table with several columns and rows and one of the cell in each row is a menu button that will open as soon as it's click.

This was working OK before I added pagination and sorting to the table.
After adding paggination and sorting , the menu for each row will only open on the first page of the pagination.

It seems that after second page, the menu will open but it does not appears on the page. It's position seems to be lower but because of pagination I do not see it.

How could I see the menu for a row that it's in the second page and after when using tables with pagination?
How can I see the menu in the page when sorting?

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Code:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";

import useStyles from "./../styles/tableStyles";
import CurrenciesContext from "./../context/currenciesContext";
import DeleteCurrencyContext from "./../context/deleteCurrencyContext";
import AddToCompareContext from "./../context/addToCompareContext";

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

const CurrencyTable = () => {
  const BILLION = 1000000000;
  const TRILLION = 1000000000000;
  const MILLION = 1000000;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const currencies = useContext(CurrenciesContext);
  const addToCompare = useContext(AddToCompareContext);
  const deleteCurrency = useContext(DeleteCurrencyContext);

  const [openTableMenus, setOpenTableMenus] = useState([]);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState("rank");

  const handleClickTableMenu = (currency, event) => {
    let tableMenus = [...openTableMenus];
    const index = currencies.indexOf(currency);
    tableMenus[index] = event.currentTarget;
    setOpenTableMenus(tableMenus);
  };

  const handleCloseTableMenu = (currency) => {
    let tableMenus = [...openTableMenus];
    const index = currencies.indexOf(currency);
    tableMenus[index] = null;
    setOpenTableMenus(tableMenus);
  };

  const handleTranformBigNum = (num) => {
    if (Math.round(num).toString().length > 12)
      return `${(num / TRILLION).toFixed(2)}T`;
    if (Math.round(num).toString().length > 9)
      return `${(num / BILLION).toFixed(2)}B`;
    if (Math.round(num).toString().length > 6)
      return `${(num / MILLION).toFixed(2)}M`;
    return num.toFixed(2);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    handleRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  const handleDeleteCurrency = (currency) => {
    console.log("delete", currency);
    deleteCurrency(currency);
  };

  const headCells = [
    {
      id: "rank",
      label: "#",
    },
    {
      id: "name",
      label: "Name",
    },
    {
      id: "priceChange1d",
      label: "24H Change",
    },
    {
      id: "price",
      label: "Price",
    },
    {
      id: "priceBtc",
      label: "Price in BTC",
    },
    {
      id: "marketCap",
      label: "Market CAP",
    },
    {
      id: "volume",
      label: "Volume 24H",
    },
  ];

  console.log("menus anchors: ", openTableMenus);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2>Currencies Table</h2>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {headCells.map((headCell) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={headCell.id}
                  align="center"
                  sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                >
                  <TableSortLabel
                    active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
                    onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
                  >
                    {headCell.label}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
              ))}
              <TableCell align="center">PRICE GRAPH (7D)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center"></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {currencies &&
              stableSort(currencies, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((currency, index) => (
                  <TableRow key={currency.id}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {currency.rank}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      {currency.name}
                      <span className={classes.grey}>-{currency.symbol}</span>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell
                      align="center"
                      className={
                        currency.priceChange1d >= 0
                          ? classes.positiveChange
                          : classes.negativeChange
                      }
                    >{`${currency.priceChange1d}%`}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      {`$${currency.price.toFixed(2)}`}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{currency.priceBtc}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      {handleTranformBigNum(currency.marketCap)}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      {handleTranformBigNum(currency.volume)}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">GRAPH</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      <IconButton
                        aria-label={`${currency.name}-more`}
                        aria-controls={`${currency.name}-menu`}
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        onClick={(event) =>
                          handleClickTableMenu(currency, event)
                        }
                      >
                        <MenuIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                      <Menu
                        id={`${currency.name}-menu`}
                        anchorEl={openTableMenus[index]}
                        keepMounted
                        open={Boolean(openTableMenus[index])}
                        onClose={(event) => handleCloseTableMenu(currency)}
                      >
                        <MenuItem
                          onClick={(event) => {
                            handleCloseTableMenu(currency);
                            addToCompare(currency);
                          }}
                        >
                          Add to Compare
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                          onClick={() => {
                            handleCloseTableMenu(currency);
                            handleDeleteCurrency(currency);
                          }}
                        >
                          Delete Row
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Menu>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50]}
        component="div"
        count={currencies.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onChangePage={(event, newPage) => handleChangePage(event, newPage)}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={(event) => handleChangeRowsPerPage(event)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CurrencyTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.
it had to do with the index of the list after using pagination.
When using pagination, the index of the item on the list will be allways from 0 to number of items per page and not the original index the item had on the list before pagination.

Please see following code to see answer in case you also have this issue.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";

import useStyles from "./../styles/tableStyles";
import CurrenciesContext from "./../context/currenciesContext";
import DeleteCurrencyContext from "./../context/deleteCurrencyContext";
import AddToCompareContext from "./../context/addToCompareContext";

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

const CurrencyTable = () => {
  const BILLION = 1000000000;
  const TRILLION = 1000000000000;
  const MILLION = 1000000;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const currencies = useContext(CurrenciesContext);
  const addToCompare = useContext(AddToCompareContext);
  const deleteCurrency = useContext(DeleteCurrencyContext);

  const [openTableMenus, setOpenTableMenus] = useState([]);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState("rank");

  const handleClickTableMenu = (currency, index, event) => {
    let tableMenus = [...openTableMenus];
    tableMenus[index] = event.currentTarget;
    setOpenTableMenus(tableMenus);
  };

  const handleCloseTableMenu = (index) => {
    let tableMenus = [...openTableMenus];
    tableMenus[index] = null;
    setOpenTableMenus(tableMenus);
  };

  const handleTranformBigNum = (num) => {
    if (Math.round(num).toString().length > 12)
      return `${(num / TRILLION).toFixed(2)}T`;
    if (Math.round(num).toString().length > 9)
      return `${(num / BILLION).toFixed(2)}B`;
    if (Math.round(num).toString().length > 6)
      return `${(num / MILLION).toFixed(2)}M`;
    return num.toFixed(2);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    handleRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  const handleDeleteCurrency = (currency) => {
    deleteCurrency(currency);
  };

  const headCells = [
    {
      id: "rank",
      label: "#",
    },
    {
      id: "name",
      label: "Name",
    },
    {
      id: "priceChange1d",
      label: "24H Change",
    },
    {
      id: "price",
      label: "Price",
    },
    {
      id: "priceBtc",
      label: "Price in BTC",
    },
    {
      id: "marketCap",
      label: "Market CAP",
    },
    {
      id: "volume",
      label: "Volume 24H",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2>Currencies Table</h2>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {headCells.map((headCell) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={headCell.id}
                  align="center"
                  sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                >
                  <TableSortLabel
                    active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
                    onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
                  >
                    {headCell.label}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
              ))}
              <TableCell align="center"></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {currencies &&
              stableSort(currencies, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((currency, index) => (
                  <TableRow key={currency.id}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {currency.rank}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      <div className={classes.icon}>
                        <img
                          src={currency.icon}
                          alt={`${currency.name} icon`}
                          width="25"
                          height="25"
                        ></img>
                      </div>
                      {currency.name}
                      <span className={classes.grey}>-{currency.symbol}</span>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell
                      align="center"
                      className={
                        currency.priceChange1d >= 0
                          ? classes.positiveChange
                          : classes.negativeChange
                      }
                    >{`${currency.priceChange1d}%`}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      {`$${currency.price.toFixed(2)}`}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">{currency.priceBtc}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      {handleTranformBigNum(currency.marketCap)}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      {handleTranformBigNum(currency.volume)}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      <IconButton
                        aria-label={`${currency.name}-more`}
                        aria-controls={`${currency.name}-menu`}
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        onClick={(event) =>
                          handleClickTableMenu(currency, index, event)
                        }
                      >
                        <MenuIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                      <Menu
                        id={`${currency.name}-menu`}
                        anchorEl={openTableMenus[index]}
                        keepMounted
                        open={Boolean(openTableMenus[index])}
                        onClose={(event) => handleCloseTableMenu(index)}
                      >
                        <MenuItem
                          onClick={(event) => {
                            handleCloseTableMenu(index);
                            addToCompare(currency);
                          }}
                        >
                          Add to Compare
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                          onClick={() => {
                            handleCloseTableMenu(index);
                            handleDeleteCurrency(currency);
                          }}
                        >
                          Delete Row
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Menu>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50]}
        component="div"
        count={currencies.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onChangePage={(event, newPage) => handleChangePage(event, newPage)}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={(event) => handleChangeRowsPerPage(event)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default CurrencyTable;
```